# Holes in Sculpt mode?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

Why is there holes in sculpt mode-[image]

I can't smooth them or draw over them and cover them up.
Does anyone know how to help?

Comment: Looks more like crease than a hole. This kind of pinching and stretching is why I prefer the Dyntopo method. Have you tried various brushes to smooth it?

Comment: It's a crease/valley. If you rotate you camera so you can see inside it so it si not obscured - you can smooth it out with smooth brush.

Comment: I did but I can still not smooth or draw over the hole.

Comment: It is still a hole in the mesh...